# Can autoformat be set to maintain spacing for named parameters in VS2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm using visual studio 2015 and want to have auto format make my code do something it doesn't do, line up the value of named parameters.  Here is what autoformat does:

```
    EMRSQL_InsertUpdate_Lab_Result(-1, Convert.ToInt32(SplitResult[1])
                                     , intEmpID
                                     , intPtID
   , strItemName: GetXMLInnerTextNullable(Node, "ResultDescription").ToString()
   , datItemDate: GetXMLInnerTextNullable(Node, "ResultEffectiveTime").ToString()
   , strFillerOrderAccessionID: GetXMLInnerTextNullable(Node, "ID").ToString()
   , strResultValue: GetXMLInnerTextNullable(Node, "ResultValue").ToString()
   , strResultUnits: GetXMLInnerTextNullable(Node, "ResultUnit").ToString()
   , strResultFlag: InterpretationCode
   , strServiceID: LOINCServiceID
   , strServiceIDType: ServiceIDType);
```

Here is what I want it to do:

```
Result = EMRSQL_InsertUpdate_Lab_Result(-1, Convert.ToInt32(SplitResult[1])
                                          , intEmpID
                                          , intPtID
, strItemName:                GetXMLInnerTextNullable(Node, "ResultDescription").ToString()
, datItemDate:                GetXMLInnerTextNullable(Node, "ResultEffectiveTime").ToString()
, strFillerOrderAccessionID:  GetXMLInnerTextNullable(Node, "ID").ToString()
, strResultValue:             GetXMLInnerTextNullable(Node, "ResultValue").ToString()
, strResultUnits:             GetXMLInnerTextNullable(Node, "ResultUnit").ToString()
, strResultFlag:              InterpretationCode
, strServiceID:               LOINCServiceID
, strServiceIDType:           ServiceIDType);
```